# @Scheduled Annotation Fails After Upgrading to Grails 3.1.9

Tags: spring, grails, scheduled-tasks

I'm using the `@Scheduled` annotations in Grails 3.1.9 and the annotated service method is not executing at all after upgrading from 3.1.0.RC2 to 3.1.9.  Downgrading back to 3.1.0.RC2 causes it to work again.

**Here's my service...**

```
package com.mycompany.app

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled

@Transactional
class InstanceSnapshotService {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 30000L, initialDelay = 30000L)
    void updateSnapshots() {
        Date start = new Date()
        log.info("Started Updating Snapshots at $start")
        ... do stuff ...
        log.info("Finished Updating Snapshots after ${new Date().time - start.time}ms")
    }    
}
```

**Here's my Application.groovy...**

```
package com.datapriviasoftware.completesso

...
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling

@EnableScheduling
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        GrailsApp.run(Application)
    }

    @Override
    void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Like I said, I had this running a few week ago before we upgraded from Grails 3.1.0-RC2 to Grails 3.1.9.  I'm not sure if that could have had anything to do with it.

Thanks you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Are you registering `InstanceSnapshotService` somewhere? You are probably missing `@Service` anotation.

Comment: Grails registers the services by convention without the `@Service` annotation, but I did try adding the annotation just in case, but to no avail. Thanks for the suggestion though. :-)

Comment: Just reverting to 3.1.0.RC2 works fine. So it appears something has changed with `@Scheduled` between 3.1.0.RC2 and 3.1.9. Investigating now to determine where.

Comment: It breaks in 3.1.7, worked up to 3.1.6. From the [3.1.7 changelog](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues?q=milestone%3Agrails-3.1.7) the most suspicious looking change is an upgrade to spring boot 1.3.5 ([release notes here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/10/spring-boot-1-3-5-released))

Comment: further, it appears that the upgrade of spring boot went from 1.3.3 to 1.3.5. The changes in 1.3.5 look unrelated to my untrained eye, so the 1.3.4 changes are suspect.

Comment: This is also related. https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/2216

Answer (score 3):

The way we were using @Scheduled broke in 3.1.7

I made a comment on [this grails issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/2216), and [Graeme Rocher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259167/graeme-rocher) said to put

`boolean lazyInit = false`

in the service. This appears to get things working again.